# git: how to track an existing configuration directory on a test VM?

Tags: git

I have a Bitnami WordPress vm on which I am experimenting with https configuration.  Its Apache configuration directory is as below and I can ssh into it.

I would rather edit files locally (macos using Sublime Text) however.

1. Apache on the VM needs to see its config (and not care about git).
2. I want to deposit changes from my mac's editing sessions onto the VM and I want to launch those commands Mac-side.
3. I am the only real person, even if the user accounts are different.
4. I don't really need to edit anything on the VM.
5. I have full root access.

I've often started tracking an existing configuration directory with Git and it works really well.  Problem is I can't figure out how to get the same workflow on a remote.

```
bitnami@debian:/opt/bitnami/apache2$ tree conf -d
conf
├── bitnami
├── extra
└── original
    └── extra
```

For some reason I didn't manage to get `git daemon` to work satisfactorily, so I ended up using git over ssh instead.  Which is fine, as I avoid having to secure git on the VM.

However I can't quite get git to work as I want.  (in both cases, I copied over the actual conf to **~/temp** beforehand).

### Try #1 git init --bare:

#### VM-side:

git init works, I see all my files + the git stuff:

```
bitnami@debian:~/temp$ cp -r /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/ .
bitnami@debian:~/temp$ cd conf
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/bitnami/temp/conf/
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ ls -ltr | tail -10
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitnami bitnami    891 Sep 22 04:07 ca.key
drwxr-xr-x 2 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:07 bitnami
drwxr-xr-x 4 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:10 refs
drwxr-xr-x 4 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:10 objects
drwxr-xr-x 2 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:10 info
drwxr-xr-x 2 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:10 hooks
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitnami bitnami     23 Sep 22 04:10 HEAD
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitnami bitnami     73 Sep 22 04:10 description
-rwxr--r-- 1 bitnami bitnami     66 Sep 22 04:10 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 bitnami bitnami   4096 Sep 22 04:10 branches
```

#### A Mac-side git clone doesn't copy any files:

```
jluc@temp$ git clone ssh://bitnami@$IP_WP2/home/bitnami/temp/conf
Cloning into 'conf'...
bitnami@192.168.1.147's password:
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
jluc@temp$ cd conf
jluc@conf$ ls -ltr
jluc@conf$
```

sure enough, no files on the mac.

#### VM-side.  Let's add them on the server.

Except it doesn't work.

```
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ git add .
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

### Try #2 git init, no --bare

#### VM-side:

```
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ cd ..
bitnami@debian:~/temp$ rm -rf conf/
bitnami@debian:~/temp$ cp -r /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/ .
bitnami@debian:~/temp$ cd conf
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/bitnami/temp/conf/.git/
```

then add everything:

```
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ git add .
bitnami@debian:~/temp/conf$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf
    new file:   bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf
    new file:   bitnami/bitnami.conf
    new file:   bitnami/httpd-2xlarge.conf
    ....
```

and commit it

```
git commit -am "just init"

[master (root-commit) a13fb20] just init
 50 files changed, 7847 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf
 create mode 100644 bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhos
 ...
```

#### Mac-side again:

clone.

```
jluc@temp$ git clone ssh://bitnami@$IP_WP2/home/bitnami/temp/conf
Cloning into 'conf'...
bitnami@192.168.1.147's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
bitnami@192.168.1.147's password:
remote: Counting objects: 45, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
remote: Total 45 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (45/45), 84.87 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
```

create a dummy file and commit it:

```
jluc@temp$ cd conf
jluc@conf$ touch test.txt
jluc@conf$ git add test.txt
jluc@conf$ git commit -am "just a test.txt file to test"
[master 3789f21] just a test.txt file to test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
```

and it errors when I push it:

```
jluc@conf$ git push origin master
bitnami@192.168.1.147's password:
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 282 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
..... more stuff...

remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ssh://192.168.1.147/home/bitnami/temp/conf
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://bitnami@192.168.1.147/home/bitnami/temp/conf'
```

I looked at a number of **git init --bare** posts, but haven't really figured out the one matching my use case.

Doesn't help that there are a number of relevant changes between git versions and that answers sometimes conflict.

Would `git config --bool core.bare true`, as per [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117823/git-push-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552052/1394353) help?  When should I run it then?  After the mac clone?  I tried doing that, and my git push origin master didn't complain, but I also did not see my new test.txt file on the VM.

And [git-how-to-start-tracking-an-existing-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992312/git-how-to-start-tracking-an-existing-project) seems relevant, but the accepted answer's link returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workflow for your case is to:

- initialize a non-bare repo as you did, but in a separate location, outside Apache.
- add your files in it
- [transform it to a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/6309)
- clone it: you can work locally, add, commit and push back to that bare repo
- before pushing, add a post-receive hook to your bare repo with a line like:

  ```
  git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/public_html/app checkout -f
  ```

That way, each time you push, the files will be checked out in their original Apache folder.
(adapt the paths to your case)

Comment: yes, that works quite well, txs.  And the post-receive hook does just the trick, with one line!